# JMeter - working with multiple tests

Tags: jmeter

I am new with JMeter and I am trying to understand how to work with multiple tests plans.

Is it possible to define multiple tests plans in a single ".jmx" file, each with its own thread groups, etc. ? Or should I save each test plan in a separate ".jmx" file?

What is the correct and common usage?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your workflow and what you are trying to achieve, the most common use case assumes collaborative work of more than one people on the JMeter test scenario. In this case [Test Fragments](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments) would be useful.

If you are trying to run several JMeter tests in parallel, the easiest option is using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper and just pass several .jmx tests to it either in command-line or through YAML configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for an approach for creating a modular JMeter test scripts.

There are many ways to achieve reusability/modularity in JMeter.

1. Test Fragment
2. Module Controller
3. Parameterized Controller
4. Include Controller

Check [this post](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-modularizing-test-scripts/) for more detailed information.

[Keyword driven framework](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-how-to-create-a-data-keyword-driven-framework-for-performance-testing/) in JMeter.

Comment: I think you didn't answer his simple question.

Answer (score 0):

I am here because I'm asking the same thing than you @SomethingSomething

From my understanding and my point of view, to have multiple tests plans, you must create several .jmx file. For instance, if you need to test different servers or application.

If you need to test multiple scenario in a same application, so combining them into in a single .jmx file should be the better option (by using Fragments or Controllers).